# PhpStorm fluent setters by default

Tags: phpstorm, setter

Every time I use "code generate" functionality for setters I need to check "Fluent setters" checkbox. Is it possible to make that checkbox enabled by default?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not possible yet: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-38880 - feel free to vote/comment for it in order to increase its priority and get notified about updates.

Comment: Should be fixed in 2019.1

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54231818/2132069

Answer (score 3):

If in fact you always prefer this behaviour, you can replace the code for a normal setter with the code for a fluent setter.

If you want to sometimes have a non fluent setter you could also switch the codes. And then check the fluent setter box to insert normal setters.

Admitted, a hacky solution, but this solved the issue for me.

[image: You can find the code here]

Comment: Good news, just a few days ago they finally fixed this issue and it will available in 2019.1 version. That's what one of their devs wrote: `The checkbox is saved per project and its state survives a restart. But the setting can't be shared since it's saved in workspace.xml.`

Answer (score 1):

I'm using PHPStorm 2019.1.3 (Mac) and pressing option+return opens a popup menu allowing me to create fluent setter.